# Let us do more to Documentation tag proposals besides watch silently or acquiesce

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

*My question is not a duplicate of the discussion question listed in the comments. This is a* [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) *asking explicitly for some new functionality to the site.*

Right now we can see Documentation tag proposals. That means we can see a lot of ones that shouldn't have been proposed, like a whole tag for [CSS Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css-selectors).

Unfortunately, we can only sit in silence or we can go along with the proposal by clicking 'Commit'.

Can we please have the ability to decline/vote against a Tag proposal, or at least *comment* on them so that the initial proposer can withdraw it?

Comment: Yes, I see this becoming a problem in several places. Lots of the popular tags are far too broad to ever be good Documentation repositories. For example, [tag:windows] could never be "documented", but yet has been proposed. I'd love to leave a comment pointing people to commit to the more appropriate [tag:winapi] proposal, instead. Same thing with the [tag:assembly]. That's far too broad; what kinds of generic things could you document about assembly language? Instead, people should be committing to specific architectures, like [tag:x86].

Answer (score 4):

On the one hand, there are a bunch of proposals that are *obviously* not going to go anywhere.

On the other hand... My experience with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s here has convinced me that folks are often quite terrible at determining whether or not a tag is useful *even when they're looking at the questions in the tag*. Expecting folks to make useful decisions on whether a tag can be effectively documented *before any documentation has been written or requested* will probably just lead to a lot of stress and pointless arguments.

We struggled with this for years on the [Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) where new Q&A sites are proposed: folks would bicker over topics all day long, even when they had no hope of getting traction. We eventually settled on a system that lets all but the most blatantly-inappropriate proposals have a go of it, but kills them off if they fail to gain any traction in a set period of time.

I think a similar system might end up working out for Docs: if a tag is proposed (but not created) in a few days, kill the proposal. If a tag is *created* but fails to garner a sufficient number of edits within a few more days, kill the tag. This would then just leave "popular nuisance" tags as the only things needing discussion and manual moderation... Which they would assuredly need anyway.

Comment: Yeah lets kill all low traffic stuff no rep anyway on these tags, we can all FGTIW and edit like crazy in java and c#

Comment: There's currently a fairly high bar for activity on a tags even to *propose* adding it to Docs, @Petter. And yet still there are folks proposing these tags, or supporting them, and then they get created and... Crickets. Not even one topic filled in. So what's the point exactly?

Comment: I'm a low traffic tagger the point is that tags like jasper-reports, machine-learning etc would be killed with a similar system and I think a lot people like me enjoy these tags and that SO should support them as high traffic tags (maybe they are even more interesting since more specialized). The comment was a provocation, sorry maybe to instinctive but still meta.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Low traffic here means ~500 questions... jasper-reports and machine-learning both have several thousand questions each.

Comment: @TylerH, trust me to get someone to commit, approve and edit in jasper-reports docs is not easy.. it would have been killed with this implementation "If a tag is proposed (but not created) in a few days, kill the proposal. If a tag is created but fails to garner a sufficient number of edits within a few more days, kill the tag" and there are even smaller tags that I think should have the honor to be able to have docs. Hence I think another solution is needed.

Comment: Just to give some numbers [css-selectors] have 7,463 questions, [jasper-reports] 6,391 while jasper-reports is main tag on questions, css-selectors probably is not. I can't really see how SO would benefit from removing docs on these kind of low-traffic tags, true less people interested and less advertisement, but still "a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"

Comment: Just to be clear, the tag activity threshold is for *proposing* the tag, @Petter. I'm suggesting that we should delete tags from docs if no one bothers actually editing them *in docs* - IOW, essentially delete things that were created but no one (or almost no one) is using. That doesn't require C# levels of activity, it just requires someone to actually want to write documentation... Which strikes me as a reasonable thing to expect.

Comment: @Shog9 how do we avoid having "hidden features of csharp" as a topic?

Comment: Stipulate that you must be a member of the Tautology Club to write it, @sklivvz... Or maybe just impose some limits on the number of examples in a topic and see what happens?

Comment: @Shog9 I'd consider a topic more similar to a question than a site. it can be too broad, too small, unclear, etc. topics need to be closeable maybe?

Comment: FWIW, @Sklivvz: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330418/are-tips-tricks-style-topics-appropriate-for-documentation