# Are 'Tips & Tricks' style topics appropriate for Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

There are some "classic" questions on Stack Overflow which were tremendously popular in their day, but which are now closed because they are not a single question with a canonical answer. As an example, [Hidden Features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python): an overly broad question with **191 answers** as I write this, each different from the last.

There are some Internet articles which cover similar topics. They are highly useful, but by modern standards inappropriate for StackOverflow, except *maybe* as a series of canonical self-answered questions to provide common dupe targets. An example of this might be [Common Python Gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/).

Provided the appropriate format is followed and information isn't lifted from external sources without attribution, are these sorts of things on-topic and appropriate as Documentation Topics and Examples?

Comment: Common gotchas would be useful, especially for JavaScript ;) . Hidden features would be interesting, but their usefulness aside from code golf is debatable, and repwhores might have a nice time.

Comment: @gcampbell I picked "hidden features" b/c I remembered that question specifically as an old-style question that reminds me of something that seems more appropo for Docs. I don't know if that's useful in other languages, but for Python it can be neat since it has some weird but useful features that don't appear much in related languages, like `else` clauses on `try` and looping constructs.

Comment: I actually like reading about hidden features, but it's tricky to decide what counts and what doesn't.

Comment: Perl is TMTOWTDI -- "There's More Than One Way To Do It".  It's good to document all the ways to do something so you can read someone else's code!

Comment: Tips & Tricks are example centric, so I guess yes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I suspect an awful lot of Docs *will* end up being "tips and tricks". Without needing a question, this sort of thing accumulates.

**And that's probably ok!**

But... Please try to categorize them. Rather than throwing them all into a massive, impossible to navigate "Tips" topic, if you write such an example try to find or create a topic where it can live comfortably.

This *should* be fairly natural. You'll note that the top "hidden feature" of Python in that old question (chaining comparison operators) [now lives comfortably under the Comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/248/comparisons/900/chain-comparisons#t=201608022222133589985) topic in Docs. You can find some of the others scattered around as well (often in topics that should probably be broken up a bit - a "loops" topic is crazy big).

In short, tips and tricks are great when they're practical - and even better when you can find them. So pick a relevant topic, write a title that reflects some useful activity, and go to town.

Comment: "Rather than throwing them all into a massive, impossible to navigate "Tips" topic" I think this is why most people feel aversion to have tips and tricks at all on documentation. If I need to sort something in Perl, I shouldn't navigate outside the "Sorting" topic and find the ["Schwartzian transform"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_Transform) in *there*, not buried (or featured) in a "Tips & Tricks" list of stuff.

Comment: ' Rather than throwing them all into a massive, impossible to navigate "Tips" topic, ' Unfortunately every topic seems massive and impossible to navigate to me at this moment. I hope time and new features will change this.

Comment: I just use search, @Two-BitAlchemist. Works surprisingly well. Content indexing has come a long way since 2008's SQLServer Full Text.

Comment: What if you're not looking for anything in particular? Say I'm new to Ruby. What do I search for?

Comment: I'd probably search for "ruby", @Two-BitAlchemist.

Comment: I meant within the tag. Navigating the topics in whatever order they're presented is not very natural or conducive to learning.

Comment: Well, that's the intent of the "overview" topic pinned to the top-right of the dashboard, @Two-BitAlchemist. Wouldn't say it's particularly useful for ruby just yet.

Comment: Oh wow... site blindness (right side in ad space) + light gray text on light gray background. I didn't even see that until you pointed it out.

Comment: "I just use search, ...Works surprisingly well." If you know what you are looking for, yes. Some sort of index to give an overview of possible topics is still a good idea, I think.